# SQL PyCharm Style when CREATE Big Query tables

Tags: sql, google-bigquery, pycharm

I am modifying the SQL PyCharm Style and I did not find any way to avoid the following transformation when creating Big Query tables:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TABLE `project.dataset.table`
```

is transformed into:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TABLE ` project.dataset.table `
```

With the blank spaces before and after the "`".
Any way to change the SQL style avoiding that?

Answer (score 0):

I think in SQL it is irrelevant for this situation "`"

```
project.dataset.table equally `project.dataset.table`
```

or trim functions

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TABLE  TRIM(` project.dataset.table `)
```

I'm sorry if I made a mistake :)

Comment: you cannot use the function `TRIM` for setting the name of a table. And the space in the table name results in an error.

Answer (score 0):

As a work around this could do the job to remove the spaces:

```
EXECUTE IMMEDIATE("CREATE OR REPLACE TABLE  "|| Replace("` project.dataset.table `"," ","") || " as Select 1 as a")
~~
```